# Disable keyboard automatically after tap on another UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uikeyboard

Let's say I have 2 textfield in my apps. The first Textfield is to input email ( keyboard show up ) and the second Textfield is for pin ( no need to show keyboard whatsoever ).

When I tap on the first textfield the keyboard showed up, and next I press on the second textfield ( this will pass to another UI & Controller ) to input PIN. So it's on different page, and I use Protocol to pass the value between controller.

I've already implement self.view.endEditing(true) and this work fine if I pressed on anywhere in the UI to dismiss the keyboard.

The problem is, when I tap on the first textfield & tap on the second immediately without tap everywhere on the UI. The keyboard from first textfield doesn't dismiss automatically and stuck up in the other controller & page.

So how do I disable the keyboard of the second textview. Because I don't need it eventually.

Few Code here.

This code is when I edit the second textfield automatically target to another controller.

```
//Implement UITextFieldDelegate
extension LoginViewController: UITextFieldDelegate{

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EnterMpinViewController") as! EnterMpinViewController
        secondViewController.pinProtocol = self
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: Try calling `self.view.endEditing(true)` in any of your second view controller's view life cycle methods.

Comment: on the second controller I dont use UITextfield, just UIlabel to showed my pin

Comment: `self.view.endEditing(true)` is for hiding the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

TextField has InputView property for custom inputs, which should be ideal for this scenario as you need secure entry for pin as well.

I have written below code snippet to show how you can use input view.

> The UIKit framework includes support for custom input views and input
>   accessory views. Your app can substitute its own input view for the
>   system keyboard when users edit text or other forms of data in a view.
>   For example, an app could use a custom input view to enter characters
>   from a runic alphabet.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var textField: UITextField?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField = UITextField()
        textField?.isSecureTextEntry = true
        textField?.textColor = UIColor.blue
        textField?.frame = CGRect.init(x: 10, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200)
        view.addSubview(textField!)

        textField?.inputView = view
        textField?.reloadInputViews()

        let btn1: UIButton = UIButton()
        btn1.frame = CGRect.init(x: 10, y: 350, width: 40, height: 40)
        btn1.setTitle("1", for: UIControlState.normal)
        btn1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btn1Tap), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(btn1)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    }

    func btn1Tap(btn1: UIButton)  {
        textField?.text = btn1.currentTitle;
    }

}
```

Comment: This tricks might be work but how about the other thing like  isSecureTextEntry = true & placeHolder

Comment: I can trick the placeHolder  by giving text and change the Color to Light Gray. But how about the `isSecureTextEntry` to make text become **** ?

Comment: Okay I missed that requirement. You need to use input view I will update my answer

Comment: I have to use button to declare this?

Comment: You must be using right? How are you taking input from numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Implement UITextField Delegate method and return false if textfield is your another textfield

```
 func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == yourAnotherTextFiled {

            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way it may be help you

```
let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2 // change 2 to desired number of seconds
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
       // Your code with delay

     let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EnterMpinViewController") as! EnterMpinViewController
        secondViewController.pinProtocol = self
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
    }
```